# Question on assigning new SSL certificate before expiration GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ssl-certificate, google-cloud-networking, google-cloud-load-balancer

We have updated and installed our new SSL certificate on GCP. Everything looks OK. The previous SSL certificate is still valid and assigned to a proxy group.

Question:

- How can we assign the new certificate to the proxy groups?
- Or does the certificate switch as soon as the previous expires and we don't have to take any action yet

Many thanks for your help

[Network tab view SSL certificates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B1DIX.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

The load balancer can serve the expired certificate if the certificate is still associated. Once you upload a new self-managed certificate, remove the older ones.

> When the SNI hostname matches CNs or SANs in more than one
> certificate, the certificate selection is based on client-specific and
> internal factors that cannot be predicted. One of the certificates
> matching the SNI is returned. The load balancer can also serve the
> expired certificate if the expired certificate is still associated
> with the target proxy.

[Multiple SSL certificates](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/ssl-certificates#multiplessl)

Comment: Many thanks John for your help! So we would have to delete the expired SSl certificate and then automatically the new certificate would be assigned automatically - is this what you suggest? 

Both certificates are serving the same domain. One is the updated one, since our current one expires as you can see. So it is just the simple extension certificate. 

How can we make sure that when we delete the still working certificate that it is replaced with the new one? Or is there anywhere in. GCP a setting where we can assign the SSl certificate?

Comment: I can see from the documentation that always the first certificate is taken. So I would assume that when the current one expires or we delete it, automatically the new one is assigned as it is the first working in the list for the domain?

Sorry for the additional question, but we want to make sure that the system is not down and that we dont have to install another SSL certificate again.

Thanks for your help John, really appreciate!

Comment: @LiveTube If you have an expired certificate **associated** with the load balance, as Google states, it can be used. You should remove expired certificates. The documentation also states **the certificate selection is based on client-specific and internal factors that cannot be predicted**. If you use **self-managed** certificates, then it is up to you to manage them.

Comment: Our certificate expires on Saturday but we have alread created and uploaded the new certificate. Our question iis: Will the updated SSL certificate been assigned automatically when the current one expires or when we delete it. So if there is no other valid certificate will Google Cloud automatically assign the valid one or do we have to point the system somewhere to this new certificate?

Comment: @LiveTube - Please read the bold portions of my last comment. The simple solution is to assign the new certificate and remove the one that will expire.